# Android market text format

Tags: android, google-play

I saw some special characters used by developers in the description of their apps.
How do I do that (for example show a star icon instead of *)?

Also - is it possible to show bold\italic\underlined text in the market description?

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071127/google-play-app-description-formatting

Comment: I had the same question. Found a full list here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071127/google-play-app-description-formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't specifically what you are rerfering to. But I would imagine that you can copy any character out of character map(on windows) and paste into the description of your app on the developer console.

Comment: It looks like you can use a little HTML as well: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling

Comment: When writing my android market description on android's developer site , I managed to insert some stars but after publishing the APP . The Stars were switchced to = signs. Maybe android does not allow special characters insertion on the descrition , but i know iphone enables this!!!

Answer (score 6):

Just copy paste the star character into your text (it is an unicode char) and you'll be set to go.

★ <-- copy paste this

Also I noticed it supports `<b>` tags, which is pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, try inserting (empty) hyperlinks. Those are rendered in a slightly darker, bolder tone than the rest of the text.