# How to include a bullet point in Google Play app description?

Tags: android, google-play

I've researched this, but only found that you can do basic formatting with < b >...< /b > and < i >...< /i > for an app description in Google Play, so does anyone know if is it possible to display a bullet (solid circle) symbol - preferably indented?

Comment: I've updated my answer with the results as promised.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering Check my answer. Its too late but serve the purpose. Live implementation over here. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sid.wifidashdow

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I don't think you can do it via HTML or Unicode. Still, when I type `•` directly into the description and save it, I can see it across page reloads, at least in the dev console (so at least the server has saved it into the database. Whether it displays on the front end or not is entirely different). However, I don't know if it shows up on the Google Play page, as that takes several hours to update.

I will edit this answer once Google Play has updated whether or not it worked.

**UPDATE**: It worked.

Comment: Do you know perhaps how to add indentation too? This is especially useful for multiple levels of bullets.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue but it does seem that HTML character entites are supported. You can check this out on [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). You can insert special characters like bullets '•' (`&bull;`), ® (`&reg;`), ™ (`&trade;`), ... etc pretty much the HTML way. This worked out for me.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how indentations can be achieved - with `&nbsp;` maybe?

Comment: Use <blockquote>...</blockquote> for indent regions.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071127/google-play-app-description-formatting/18746972#18746972
Upvote his answer. It must have taken ages to confirm all these.

Comment: @DominicCerisano As per his answer, blockquote only renders correctly on the Google Play app and not on the website

Comment: @ban-geoengineering Just go to any website which has Unicode em space. Copying the character is a bit tricky because it's just a space so it's hard to see where it is. Try a website like https://codepoints.net/U+2003?lang=en which has an actual "copy to clipboard" button you can click.

Answer (score 6):

This is not bullet but you can consider it. As there is nothing like big dot.

I used New Moon symbol in the description and its working fine. 
http://emojipedia.org/new-moon-symbol/

⚫ Black Circle

New Moon

Full Moon

Diamond With a Dot

Small Orange Diamond

⚙ Gear

Black Flag

White Flag

▶ Play Button

⏩ Fast-Forward Button

⭕ Heavy Large Circle

✴ Eight-Pointed Star

◼ Black Medium Square

◽ White Medium-Small Square

◾ Black Medium-Small Square

⬛ Black Large Square

Also you can use full moon character.

You just need to copy and paste it over description. Below is the result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but they are all appearing as black dots to me. Also shown as black dots on your Google Play listing - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sid.wifidashdow - both when viewed on computer and on Android device.

Comment: On playstore I only implemented dot. All other are examples that you can implement. Above all are supported

Comment: I always come back to this answer just to copy a bullet from here