# Is there any tools to create a document for android project?

Tags: android, documentation

I have created one android project,i would like to upload my project on market.But before that i need to create a document for my project right?

Can any one tell me is there any tools to create a document for android project?

Here i am using Ubunto 12.

I couldn't find any tools so far through Google as per my knowledge.

Suggestions please

Thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: What kind of document do you mean?

Comment: @Egor documentation in the sense...have to describe about my project before going to upload my apk to market right? that y im asking is there any free tools available

Comment: The only thing you need to write is the app's product details and i think any text editor should do the trick...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're talking about the page of your application on Google Play, it's generated from the information you gave in the [Developer Console](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/index.html) when publishing your application.

You can provide a title, a description and some graphic assets (screenshots, icon, etc.). The description is plain text with *little* html markup support, you won't find a better tool than the integrated text editor to write it. There's no official list of the available formatting features, but see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071127/google-play-app-description-formatting) for an extensive user feedback.

Comment: No..no im not asking you,how to upload my apk on market.If you see any android app on play-store, every application will contain some description about its task right?(like texts and app screen shots). So that i am asking you is there any tools like text editor to create like those descriptions

Comment: Well as i say on the comment in your post, it's mainly plain text with some HTML formatting. Since few HTML markups work, i think you should write it by hand.