# How to add indentation to the play store app description?

Tags: android, indentation, google-play

It's a very simple question.

I've published [**an app**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager) , and in the description I have some bullets that need to have indentation.

How do I add indentation to the app's description on the play store?

Comment: One hundred thousand downloads, impressive

Comment: @AviParshan Thanks. It's actually at least 200K now, but the number of active users is a lot less than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've found a workaround:

for empty space, use "&#8195"; . just put this string as it is inside the play store description.

For example, if you wish to put a bullet with 2 spaces before it, use (without the '"') .

```
"&#8195;&#8195;•"
```

This is based on [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746972/878126).

Also, you can just put the real character instead (without the '"'):

```
" "
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the description of even Google published apps, this doesn't appear to be possible via markup - you simply have to do the bullets yourself, which looks ok for one level, but as you have found not very extendable to multi level bullets.

For example

- [Google Earth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.earth) uses asterisks for bullets
- [Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) has bullets, (but only one level)
- [Google+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus) uses hyphens for bullets

I suggest that rather than use bullets and then hyphens as your 2 levels, you try how you think bullets and two bullet characters look as your two levels.

EDIT: A [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746972/3383428) detailed the HTML tags you can use, so one possible workaround is to have your first level bullets say be bold (using <b>) and the second level bullets normal or italic (Using <i>).

Comment: Is there maybe blank characters that can be used ? like whitespaces ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, all whitespace at the start of a paragraph is stripped, and what you think of as bulleted lines are each treated as their own paragraph

Comment: Isn't there any way to overcome this? Any workaround whatsoever? I know for sure that there are some HTML tags that are supported. Isn't there any tag for this?

Comment: All the advice that Google gives is simply that you can have up to 4000 characters.  I've never found any HTML tags that work - what ones do you think have an effect?

Comment: OK - I've found the previous answer that mentioned HTML tags, which I see you have already commented on. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18746972/3383428