# How to format the Google Paly App title to be bold or italic?

Tags: android, formatting, google-play

I know that I can format the Google Play store app description to be bold or italic.

Is it possible to do the same for App title?

I want to format the title as follows,

Test *App*

In the above title text "App" text should be italic format.

Please help me to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Play app description formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071127/google-play-app-description-formatting)