# Google Play Store Description Size & Color

Tags: android, html, google-play

Is there a way to change the text size & color in the Google Play Description using something like `<font size='16' color='#f26522'>`? If so I can't seem to figure it out. I'm trying to add something to my icon pack description that I'd like the font size to be bigger to the rest and the color to be red with the color code above. If this question has been asked before I'm sorry I didn't see a title that matched what I'm asking.

Comment: Yes, it had been asked before. You must have googled that before. Here is one from stackoverflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071127/google-play-app-description-formatting

Comment: I seen that question @Gamma but I couldn't comment since I don't have a rep of 50