# Unicodes in Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Can someone tell me how to add HTML Unicode to my Application title, such ass "NULL" HTML Unicode or anything. Because I kept trying that for days now and nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of [Google Play app description formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071127/google-play-app-description-formatting)

If you just want some decorations on your title, please look at this https://emojipedia.org/ and http://smiley.cool/en/emoticons.php , These works for Google Play.