# Huawei AppGallery app description formatting

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

Google's Play Store [supports quite a bit of markup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18746972/467650) in the app description. How is that for Huawei's AppGallery? I couldn't find any information on that anywhere.

I did try to use `<b>…</b>` and `<font color="…">…</font>`, but those show up as plain text (with the tags visible) - both in the AppGallery app and on its website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML tags are not supported on the Huawei AppGallery. As far as I know it is being worked on but there hasn't been any given time frame as to when they will be released. I'll keep you posted as soon as there are news on this subject.

Comment: Today I found a message saying _"HTML tags are not supported. The input will be displayed as text."_ on the page with the app information.