# How to customize app description like font size, font color etc. in google play console in 2022?

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I read some articles about How to customize app description like font size etc. They all are telling about html tags but I don't understand how to use html tags in google play console? If you tell me How to customize the app description in google play console step by step with the help of images. It will be great.

Comment: Please check this link if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071127/google-play-app-description-formatting

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: @AshutoshOjha I have seen this post early but I don't understand how to do rich formatting?