# How to set Text Format?

Tags: java, android, text, textview

A normal scoreboard text is like this

[image]

so i want to make te text format like this

[image]

this is the code

```
    score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ct);
    score.setText(String.valueOf(gamescore));

                    if (gamescore > highscore){
                        high.setText(String.valueOf(gamescore));
                     }
```

Anyone can explain? Thank's

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android market text format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831474/android-market-text-format)

Comment: Use ```String.format("%06d", gamescore)```.

Comment: @Mohit This isn't even remotely similar to that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) method along with the [formatter syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax). `String.format()` can be used to left-pad a string with zeroes, just like you want.

This code will give you the results that you want: `high.setText(String.format("%06d", gamescore));`

Let's look at what's going on in detail. We are using this syntax: `%[flags][width]conversion`

- Always begin the format string syntax with a `%`.
- Following `%` is `0`, the zero-padding `flag`. This tells the formatter that the result will be zero-padded.
- After the zero-padding `flag` is the `width`, or the minimum number of digits we want; in this case, `6`.
- Lastly, specify the conversion type. The desired result is formatted as a decimal integer, so we use `d`.

Here is an example:

```
int gamescore = 100;
String result = String.format("%06d", gamescore);
System.out.println(result);
```

Output: `000100`

Comment: oh Thank you Mitch, its work! but can the text format get animated by using Value Animator?

Comment: @Ricci I've never used the ValueAnimator unfortunately, so I can't help you there.